# Import site-specific data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The data on the page is delivered as follows:
https://int.soccerway.com/international/europe/uefa-champions-league/20192020/group-stage/r54142/

[image]

1 - Below each schedule is a link to the match.
2 - I would like to import all data at once.
3 - The result I seek would be as follows:

[image]

4 - **Import separately, I can, but as they are separate formulas, it takes a long time, I would like a way to import all at once, for a formula only if it were possible.**

5 - The Xpath are:

```
"//*[@class='date no-repetition']"
"//*[@class='score-time status']/a"
"//*[@class='score-time status']/a/@href"
```

6 - An important detail, I indicated the `'score-time status'` because there are games that appear as `'score-time score'` but these cannot be imported.

7 - There is another detail that complicates, the time comes with spaces between the sign of `:`, so for him I use the `=SUBSTITUTE(," ","")`

**Is there any way to do this that I want?**
I've tried using `={;;}` to import the data, but can't make calls to more than two `=IMPORTXML()`.
I also tried for `=IMPORTHML()` but it can't fetch the links from each of the below-hours matches and the date also appears in only one of the games...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### xpath:

Unfortunately, I couldn't find the xpath for directly retrieving the 3 values in your question. So in this answer, the following xpath are used.

- Date: `//td[@class='date no-repetition']/span`
- Time: `//td[@class='score-time status']/a/span`
- URL: `//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href`

#### Sample formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({IMPORTXML(A1,"//td[@class='date no-repetition']/span"),IMPORTXML(A1,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/span"),"https://"&IMPORTXML(A1,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href")})
```

- In this formula, the URL of `https://int.soccerway.com/international/europe/uefa-champions-league/20192020/group-stage/r54142/` is put to the cell "A1".
- Retrieved 3 values are put to the column "A", "B" and "C".

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- In above case, I think that the time zone might be the place when the values are retrieved by IMPORTXML.
- If you want to change the timezone to your own Spreadsheet, how about the following sample formula?

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA({IMPORTXML(A1,"//td[@class='date no-repetition']/span/@data-value")/86400+DATE(1970,1,1),IMPORTXML(A1,"//td[@class='date no-repetition']/span/@data-value")/86400+DATE(1970,1,1),"https://"&IMPORTXML(A1,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href")})
  ```

  - In this case, please set the format to the column "A" and "B".
  - In above formula, the date and time is retrieved the unix time. This value is converted to the serial number. So the converted value can be used as the date and time at Spreadsheet.

#### References:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)

If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: It was exactly what I needed. So let me get this straight: When I want everything to be in one column I put it ```;``` and when I want it to divide into several columns I need to put the formulas separated by ```,``` ... Is that so?

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying. When `;` is used, each element is put to the row direction. When `,` is used, each element is put to the column direction. For example, `={"a1";"a2";"a3"}` and `={"b1","c1","d1"}` are put to the cell "A1" and "B1", `a1,a2,a3` are put to the cells "A1,A2,A3", respectively and `b1,c1,d1` are put to the cells "B1,C1,D1", respectively. For example, `={"a1","b1","c1";"a2","b2","c2";"a3","b3","c3"}` is put to the cell "A1", the values are put to the cells "A1:C3". If my understanding of your replying is not correct, please tell me.

Comment: There was a big problem with me about this ... The spreadsheet in Brazil uses ```;``` instead of ```,```. Now it was all explained why it always went wrong. I would have to reverse what I was doing. Thank you so much for the explanation!